# read video frames from specified times

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

`AVassetReader` has the property `timeRange`. Which allow frames to be read from specified time. here is the code.

```
    CMTimeRange timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(startTime, kCMTimePositiveInfinity);
 mAssetReader.timeRange = timeRange;
```

Here`mAssetReader`is an object of `AVAssetReader`. and for e.g.. startTime is `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.987654,1000000);`.

but mAssetReader always read buffer from starting.
Is something wrong in creation of `CMtimeRange`??

Comment: sorry for the false alarm. while conversion of seconds to CMTime I was passing the wrong value....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something but it looks like inTimeRange is not declared..

```
CMTimeRange inTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(startTime, kCMTimePositiveInfinity);
mAssetReader.timeRange = inTimeRange;
```

Does that work for you?